# use jquery to set the text of the alert to text echoed from a php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP file `myFile.php` that echoes a random string from an array of strings into the screen. I want to run that php file and have the output pop up in a javascript alert. I took a crack at the syntax with `alert($.ajax({ url: 'getRejection.php' }));`

But it is not quite right , it alerts `[object Object]`.

How do I do this?

Comment: You might have to place your alert in the success area of the AJAX call as you will probably need to convert from JSON string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the jquery documentation for `ajax`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You want to use the `success` callback to run when the ajax call succeeds.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getRejection.php',
    success: function(data) { alert(data) }
});
```

Also, a note of advice: use full paths for urls, not relative url paths. Like this `url: '/getRejection.php'` not like this `url: 'getRejection.php'`

Answer (score 0):

You may use JSON by making your php file to echo its output in JSON format as follows:

```
echo "{\n";
  echo "\"txt\":";
  echo $TheRandomText;
  echo "\n";
  echo "}";
```

The previous step may be easily done as [Joe Frambach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253312/joe-frambach) suggestion like the following:

```
echo json_encode(array('txt' => $TheRandomText));
```

And then using Jquery do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $.getJSON('getRejection.php',{
          format: "json"
        }).done(function(data){
          alert(data.txt);
        });     
      });
```

However you have to get assured from the path to `getRejection.php`. In this case it is supposed to be at the same directory with your file.

Also you have to be sured that `getRejection.php` does not echo anything else text in JSON format to void the corruption of JSON query.

Comment: Let php encode the json string for you, and avoid the nested quote mess. `echo json_encode(array('txt'=>$TheRandomText));`